# Open Multiple text files and call function

Tags: python

Below code works perfectly, where it opens one text files and function `parse_messages` gets as parameter

```
def parse_messages(hl7):
    hl7_msgs = hl7.split("MSH|")
    hl7_msgs = ["{}{}".format("MSH|", x) for x in hl7_msgs if x]
    for hl7_msg in hl7_msgs:
       #does something..

with open('sample.txt', 'r') as f:
    hl7 = f.read()
df = parse_messages(hl7)
```

But now I have multiple text files in directory. I want to do open each one then call from `parse_messages` function. Here is what I tried so far.

But this only read last text file, not all of them

```
import glob
data_directory = "C:/Users/.../"
hl7_file = glob.glob(data_directory + '*.txt')

for file in hl7_file:
    with open(file, 'r') as hl7:
    hl7 = f.read()
df = parse_messages(hl7)
```

Comment: Indent your code properly. It has syntax errors in some places and makes no sense in others. Python is space-sensitive

Comment: your `hl7` readout from files are being overwrite at every iteration, leaving only the last read file, you might wanna append them into list or string

Comment: @MadPhysicist I just editted. It was from copy paste

Comment: of course it only reads the last text file, you store each file in hl7, only to overwrite it with the next file. Once you have overwritten all of them, then you call parse messages.

Comment: @Skycc I append them to new list but how do I open each one from a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your read file loop `for file in hl7_file`, you are overwrite `hl7` at every iteration leaving only the last read store at `hl7`
You probably wanna concatenate all contents of the files together

```
hl7 = ''
for file in hl7_file:
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        hl7 += f.read()

df = parse_messages(hl7) # process all concatenate contents together
```

or you can call `parse_messages` function inside the loop with df list store the results as below

```
df = []
for file in hl7_file:
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        hl7 = f.read()
        df.append(parse_messages(hl7))
# df[0] holds the result for 1st file read, df[1] for 2nd file and so on
```

Comment: This work perfectly thanks! I was actually looking something more like second answer :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: check your parse_messages function, it should return your expected result be it string or list at the end, looks like you are running `df.append(parse_messages)` instead of `df.append(parse_messages(hl7))` when you got that error

Comment: it worked, instead of copying I was typing, and I guess I didnt type all of it :)

Answer (score 0):

**This should work, if I understood what you want to do**

```
import os

all = []
files = [x for x in os.listdir() if x.endswith(".txt")]
for x in files:
    with open(x, encoding='utf-8','r') as fileobj:
        content = fileobj.read()
        all.append(parse_message(content))
```